TypeErrors when upgrading existing angular-calendar project to Angular 18
I'm upgrading an existing project to Ionic 8 and Angular 18. The project uses the angular-calendar component and was previously working fine. In the upgraded environment I am getting following errors:
ERROR TypeError: excluded.some is not a function
    getWeekViewHeader calendar-utils.js:190
    Angular 47
    RxJS 6
    Angular 20
    RxJS 47
    _ref2 crud-service.ts:28
    Angular 7 core.mjs:7404:22 ERROR TypeError: ctx.view is undefined
    Angular 46
    RxJS 6
    Angular 20
    RxJS 47
    _ref2 crud-service.ts:28
    Angular 9 core.mjs:7404:22
    Angular 15
    RxJS 6
    Angular 20
    RxJS 47
    _ref2 crud-service.ts:28
    Angular 21
    onFinishCallback animation-eab5a4ca.js:704
    afterAnimation animation-eab5a4ca.js:485
    afterAnimation animation-eab5a4ca.js:484
    animationFinish animation-eab5a4ca.js:500
    animationFinish animation-eab5a4ca.js:502
    onfinish animation-eab5a4ca.js:522
    (Async: EventHandlerNonNull)
    initializeWebAnimation animation-eab5a4ca.js:521
    initializeAnimation animation-eab5a4ca.js:530
    play animation-eab5a4ca.js:675
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    play animation-eab5a4ca.js:669
    play animation-eab5a4ca.js:713
    play animation-eab5a4ca.js:712
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    play animation-eab5a4ca.js:669
    _ref4 overlays-e7b9d6d9.js:714
    Babel 3
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    _asyncToGenerator Babel
    overlayAnimation overlays-e7b9d6d9.js:696
    _ref overlays-e7b9d6d9.js:530
    Babel 3
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    _asyncToGenerator Babel
    present overlays-e7b9d6d9.js:504
    present ion-loading.entry.js:205

The main.ts file looks like this:
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { enableProdMode, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { browserLocalPersistence, indexedDBLocalPersistence, provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { IonicModule, isPlatform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideHttpClient, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideRouter, withPreloading, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { routes } from './app/app-routing.module';
import { CalendarModule, DateAdapter } from 'angular-calendar';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule, provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { adapterFactory } from 'angular-calendar/date-adapters/date-fns';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFi from '@angular/common/locales/fi';

import { firebaseConfig } from './config/app.config';

enableProdMode();

registerLocaleData(localeFi);

export function translationLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideFirebaseApp( () => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      if (isPlatform('android')) {
        auth.setPersistence(indexedDBLocalPersistence);
      } else {
        auth.setPersistence(browserLocalPersistence);
      }
      return auth;
    }),
    provideRouter(routes, withPreloading(PreloadAllModules)),
    importProvidersFrom(
      IonicModule.forRoot(),
      IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
      ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
        enabled: !isPlatform('android'),
        registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
      }),
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: (translationLoader),
          deps: [HttpClient]
        }
      }),
      CalendarModule.forRoot({
        provide: DateAdapter,
        useFactory: adapterFactory
      }),
    )
  ]
}).catch(err => console.error(err));

And the imports in the calendar.ts page:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { PopoverController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { CalendarModule } from 'angular-calendar';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { PopoverCalendar } from '../popovers/popover-calendar/popover-calendar';

import { AuthService, CalendarConfigurationService, CrudService, DateTimeService, Loader, Toasts } from '../../providers';


import { Subject } from 'rxjs'


The calendar component is called in the `calendar.html` page:

      <div *ngIf="calendarView && calendarConfig">
        <mwl-calendar-week-view
          locale="fi"
          [refresh]="refresh"
          [dayStartHour]="calendarConfig.dayStartHour"
          [dayEndHour]="calendarConfig.dayEndHour"
          [viewDate]="calendarView.date"
          [weekStartsOn]="1"
          [hourDuration]="60"
          [hourSegments]="calendarConfig.hourSegments"
          [excludeDays]="calendarConfig.excludeDays"
          [events]="events"
          (eventClicked)="handleEvent($event)"
          (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
        >
        </mwl-calendar-week-view>


How can I make the ```angular-calendar``` work for Angular 18?



Why not use the ionic calendar component that it provides and already installed on your projct?

@StackOverHoes The old calendar was custom-made and doesn't allow the same freedom when it comes to drag and drop and move events around.

Have your tried to up/downgrade a version of this calendar component to see if that works?
